# How to generate unique 56 bit key for a given input string

Tags: encryption, hash, cryptography, chat, des

This is part of my homework question (but this is not the actual question),

In my question professor asked me to generate a unique 56 bit key to encrypt and decrypted a message. Both the sender and receiver shares a pass-phrase (password) only. There is no key exchange here.

How to get unique 56 bit key with the help of a pass-phrase??

Can i use hash? but how to get 56 bit hash value ??

Question : (relevant part)
Messanger app:
1) Alice and Bob share the same password (or passphrase), they must use the
password to set up the tool to correctly encrypt and decrypt messages shared
between each other.
2) Each message during Internet transmission must be encrypted using a 56-bit
key 
3) DONOT directly use the password as the key, you have to generate the same
key between Alice and Bob to encrypt messages. 
.......
.....

Answer (score 1):

The keyword is [Key derivation functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function)